# How can I extract that list of denominator and numerator from a SymPy equation?

Tags: python, sympy

I have some code like this here that describes an expression in `SymPy` (https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html):

```py
s = sympy.Symbol('s')
K = 1/(3*s**3 + 2*s**2 + 1*s + 1)
```

Here is the same Transfer Function but in `control` (https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) this is the syntax:

```py
den = [ 1 ]
nom = [ 3, 2, 1, 1 ]
control.TransferFunction(den, num)
```

So, we need to give it a list. 
My question is:
How can I extract that list of `den` and `num` from a SymPy equation? Also is there may be a better way of creating Transfer Functions in SymPy?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by `Transfer Function`?

Comment: @Anwarvic A transfer function like in Control Engineering. A function in the S plane
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function

Comment: Altho I guess its not that import really for SymPy, I called it like that because `control` thinks of it as that

Comment: Nvm, I solved the problem myslef. Gonna post the solution in a few minutes

Comment: Great... good job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Poly` has an `all_coeffs` method that can be applied to the identified numerator and denominator of a rational expression, e.g.

```py
import sympy as sp
s = sp.Symbol('s', rational=True)
eq=1/(2*s**2 + 3*s + 4)
top, bot = [[float(i) for i in sp.Poly(i, s).all_coeffs()] for i in eq.as_numer_denom()]
import control as co
co.TransferFunction(top, bot)
```

Comment: lol i just posted my own solution, but I think yours may be better. Check mine and say what you think

Comment: okay, I see that your solution has that problem that I had to solve, check my solutions for it, its basically because sympy make this list out of sympy objects not floats or ints

Comment: The problem with constants (independent of `s` or, in my case `x`) can be handled elegantly by creating a Poly with the symbol of interest as I have done. I am biased, but I would vote for my solution. ;-)

Comment: The problem with yours is that the co.TransferFunction() takes two lists of normal python numbers. When you try to give it a sympy number it crashes. So I actually think that combining our solution will be best. I will use your way of creating those 2 lists in a tuple and convert them into lists of floats via a loop :)

Comment: I updated the solution to give floats; it will raise if the numbers are not actually numbers, too.

Comment: Okay, it's great! I accepted it as the solutions, tho if u could edit it and show that u can actually use `sympy.Symbols('s', rational=True)` so that any symbol can be used as `x` here that would be perfect because it would be very general :D